# Downloading XLS from URL

Tags: javascript, ubuntu-16.04, wget, rhino

I'm trying to pull data, using an Ubuntu 16.04LTS server, from a website that uses JavaScript to export data into an XLS file.

https://www.adfg.alaska.gov/sf/FishCounts/index.cfm?ADFG=main.displayResults

Has a link called **Export as Excel Spreadsheet** 
which gives you this link here

https://www.adfg.alaska.gov/sf/FishCounts/index.cfm?ADFG=export.excel&countLocationID=40&year=2017&speciesID=420

I tried using the command user$ wget rhino -weblink-
but it compiles with errors 79 Errors.

I don't know very much about programming, I'm just trying to automatically pull the data on a daily basis, and run a BASH script that calculates data from the spreadsheet for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Norrin

That URL worked properly without JS execution.
Here is the command that I use:

`curl -L -o FishCount.xls 'https://www.adfg.alaska.gov/sf/FishCounts/index.cfm?ADFG=export.excel&countLocationID=40&year=2017&speciesID=420'`

Be careful that **use the single-quote to wrap URL**. Otherwise BASH/SHELL will misinterpret `&` as background process.